# Struggling with asset pipeline: The asset "{name}" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, sprockets

As part of ongoing efforts to migrate a legacy app from Rails 3 to Rails 6, I'm trying to figure out the best way to move forward with assets and whatnot.

I'm struggling with the following issue, when I try to add a specific asset:

```
<%= image_tag 'images/shared/logos/image.svg' %>
```

The image is present on:

```
app/assets/images/shared/logos/image.svg
```

And yet I get the error I mentioned on the title:

```
The asset "images/shared/logos/image.svg" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

Any advice on how to set up newer Rails to handle assets would be greatly appreciated, I'm a little confused over the whole sprockets vs webpacker thing and I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to move forward.

Comment: You don't need `images`, it is the root of the search path. `<%= image_tag 'shared/logos/image.png' %>` should suffice.

Comment: Rails has a million different ways to set up the asset pipeline. It's confusing and fragmented and doesn't make any sense in the context of an "opinionated framework".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Rails setup dosn't allow to add directories to the images folder.
You could change this in the config or simply store alle images directly into the images folder.

To change in config add the following in `config/application.rb`

```
config.assets.path <<< Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'shared', 'logos')
```

Comment: Although you can add directories to the asset path, it is very much not true that you can't add directories to the images folder.

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3):

The Rails asset helpers search a set of specified asset paths (`Rails.application.config.assets.paths`) for assets.

I'm not sure about Rails 3, but in later versions of Rails the default search paths include specific subdirectories under `app/assets` (`app/assets/stylesheets`, `app/assets/images`, etc.), but not `app/assets` itself.

So, you can drop 'images' from the start of your relative path (in fact you need to):

```rb
<%= image_tag 'shared/logos/image.svg' %>
```

If your existing app has lots lots of assets defined that way, you could try putting `app/assets` directly to the search path by adding the following to `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```rb
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets')
```

That will allow Rails to find your assets while you work through the migration.

Comment: I tried removing the `images` from the start and I still get the same error.

Comment: And no leading slash (otherwise Rails treats it as absolute)? In the console what does `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` have in it?

Comment: It's a long paste. I'll add the relevant things: 

=> ["/home/user/rails-migration/app/assets/config",
 "/home/user/rails-migration/app/assets/images",
 "/home/user/rails-migration/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/user/rails-migration/app/assets/legacy",
 "/home/user/rails-migration/app/assets/public",
 "/home/user/rails-migration/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/user/rails-migration/vendor/assets/images",
 "/home/user/rails-migration/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/user/rails-migration/vendor/assets/stylesheets",

The rest is gems.

Comment: It doesn't include the nested assets/images path but it does include the root.

Comment: Also I don't really have assets on the root of `app/assets`. I'm starting to think that it might be better to just kill all subfolders and move all images to the app/images folder...